# How to add and remove background images in css on clicking a link on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, onclick

Ive that small Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5XXdJ/

```
    <img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg" /><br />

    <a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">DE</a>
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink2">EN</a>
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink3">FR</a>

$(function() {
 $('.menulink').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
 });

$('.menulink2').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg");
 });

     $('.menulink3').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333");
 });
});
```

It works fine but my problem is:

I need to add an background image to every linkclass for selected/active state and inactive/default state, if i click another link on page.

For example the link "de" has default a white bg-image and if i click the link the bg-image changes to a black image for selected state.

If i click now "en" it will change the "de" link back into inactive state with the white background image and set the "en" bg-image-link into selected state-imagelink and will remove it if another link will be clicked.

I hope someone has an idea :)

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you talking about changing the big img, or the color behind the link itself?  Are you trying for something like radio-buttons?

Comment: No, i want to change the bg image if i click a link, for example: de has a white bg image if i click it it will be yellow, en has an red bg image if i click on that bg-image from de-link will change back to white, and the default bg image from en will change from red to any other color for example blue.

Comment: @Susan I have added another solution, i think it will the right solution what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('.menulink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#bg").toggleClass('cls2')
    });

    $('.menulink2').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#bg").toggleClass('cls3')
    });

    $('.menulink3').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#bg").toggleClass('cls4')
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/5XXdJ/39/ 
I did changes on your fiddle, this fiddle could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably add references to the different images from CSS-classes, and then add/remove them as necessary in the JavaScript. For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HTL2p/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg" /><br />
<!-- same class on all 3 -->
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">DE</a>
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">EN</a>
<a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">FR</a>
```

CSS:

```
/* The default (or "not selected") style */
.menulink {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/333");
}

.menulink.selected {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg");
}
```

​
JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menulink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.menulink.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont want to change the js code wich is inside :) thats a function i would like to use for another script.

Comment: Im sorry i mean: i would like to use for each link his own 2 images for inactive and active, so i have to add that function three times for each link? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img src="http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg" id="bg" /><br />
 <div id="links">
  <a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink">DE</a>
  <a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink2">EN</a>
  <a href="" title="Switch" class="menulink3">FR</a>
 </div>

<style>
   .active{
     background-image: url("http://placehold.it/333");
   }
</style>


    $(function() {    
     $('#links a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var className = $(this).attr('class');
     if (className == 'menulink') {
        $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
    } else if (className == 'menulink2')  {
         $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg");
    } else {
         $("#bg").attr('src',"http://placehold.it/333");
    }
    $('#links a').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

     $(this).addClass('active');

 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5XXdJ/38/

Comment: Thank you thats nice, but what if i have for each link his own images? not one for all? That was my problem wich i cant figure out :) For example: de has one black and one white image for active and inactive. en has yellow and green and fr has brown and red?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, i think you are looking for this kind of jquery

**$(this).css("background-image", "url(/active.jpg)");**

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="menulink" style="height:300px;width:300px"></div></br>
<div id="links">
  <a href="" title="Switch" id="menulink" class="menulink">DE</a>
  <a href="" title="Switch" id="menulink2">EN</a>
  <a href="" title="Switch" id="menulink3">FR</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menulink {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/333/3ef/img/picture1.jpg");
}
.menulink2 {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/333/fe3/img/picture2.jpg");
}
.menulink3 {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/333");
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {    
    $('#links a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var id= $(this).attr('id');
      $('#container').attr('class', '');
      $('#links a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('class', '');
      });
     $('#' +id).addClass(id);
     $('#container').addClass(id);       
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5XXdJ/49/